# SQL Server Query For Balance to appear only once if party name occurs multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am using MS SQL Server 2012 Express Advanced Edition.

My current table structure of one of the accounts table with data is as follows.

```
PARTY        DEBIT        CREDIT        
----------------------------------------
A            1000         NULL
B            NULL         2500
C            2000         NULL
A            NULL         5000
B            3500         NULL
A            10000        NULL
A            4500         NULL
```

I want to achieve following query result.

```
PARTY        DEBIT        CREDIT        BALANCE        
-----------------------------------------------
A            1000         NULL          10500
B            NULL         2500           1000
C            2000         NULL           2000
A            NULL         5000           NULL
B            3500         NULL           NULL
A            10000        NULL           NULL
A            4500         NULL           NULL
```

I want total closing balance of a party occuring just once against that party name, not repeating balance on the same party.

**For Example, Closing balance of PARTY A, will be 10500, and PARTY A appears multiple times, so I want closing balance to appear with only first record of PARTY A as shown in desired result. And so on with other parties.**

In short, **I want closing balance to appear only once against party name** irrespective of the multiple appearance of that party.

I tried with following query but it gives balance on each occurrence of party.

```
select
PARTY,
DEBIT,
CREDIT,
(select PARTY,SUM(DEBIT)-SUM(CREDIT) from ACCOUNTS where PARTY=A.PARTY group by PARTY) as BALANCE
from
ACCOUNTS A
```

Comment: How are you arriving at a closing balance of `10500` for `A`?  The sample data does not appear to support this.

Comment: A is having total debit of 1000+10000+4500=15500, and credit of 5000 so balance of 10500.

Comment: Your desired result set could be tough to generate because it is not clear how you want to join the calculation to the original table.  Actually, why do you want the result to appear this way?

Comment: I have added a try out query. Basically I need this because I want to show closing balance of that party with showing all the transaction records.If closing balance occurs multiples times, result will be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some column to maintain the ordering, you could try an analytic function along these lines:  get the total for the group (party), then use that as a subquery to display only the balance for the first item in the group. I tried this with Postgresql, you would need to check the syntax for your dbms.

Inner query:

```
SELECT id, party, debit, credit
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN debit IS NULL THEN -credit ELSE debit END) OVER (PARTITION BY party ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) balance
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY party ORDER BY id) AS row_number
  FROM accounts;
```

Result:

```
 id | party | debit | credit | balance | row_number 
----+-------+-------+--------+---------+------------
  1 | A     |  1000 |        |   10500 |          1
  4 | A     |       |   5000 |   10500 |          2
  6 | A     | 10000 |        |   10500 |          3
  7 | A     |  4500 |        |   10500 |          4
  2 | B     |       |   2500 |    1000 |          1
  5 | B     |  3500 |        |    1000 |          2
  3 | C     |  2000 |        |    2000 |          1
```

Wrapped:

```
SELECT party, debit, credit
      ,CASE WHEN row_number = 1 THEN balance ELSE NULL END AS balance
  FROM (SELECT id, party, debit, credit
              ,SUM(CASE WHEN debit IS NULL THEN -credit ELSE debit END) OVER (PARTITION BY party ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) balance
              ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY party ORDER BY id) AS row_number
          FROM accounts) x
  ORDER BY id;
```

Result:

```
 party | debit | credit | balance 
-------+-------+--------+---------
 A     |  1000 |        |   10500
 B     |       |   2500 |    1000
 C     |  2000 |        |    2000
 A     |       |   5000 |        
 B     |  3500 |        |        
 A     | 10000 |        |        
 A     |  4500 |        |
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve doesn't make sense to me. But if you still want to do that, then you need to have a primary key in your balance table. For the example I'm taking ID field of type int as a primary key.

Using below sql query you can achieve your desired result:

```
SELECT A.PARTY, A.DEBIT, A.CREDIT, B.BALANCE FROM BALANCE A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, PARTY, (ISNULL(SUM(DEBIT), 0) - ISNULL(SUM(CREDIT),0)) AS BALANCE FROM BALANCE GROUP BY PARTY) B
ON A.ID = B.ID
ORDER BY A.ID
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6323/5)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
SELECT party,
  debit,
  credit,
  DECODE(row_num,1,balance,NULL) balance
FROM
  (SELECT party,
    debit,
    credit,
    SUM((NVL(debit,0))-(NVL(credit,0))) over(PARTITION BY party) balance,
    row_number() over(PARTITION BY party order BY party) row_num
  FROM
    ( SELECT 'A' PARTY, 1000 DEBIT, NULL CREDIT FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', NULL , 2500 FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C', 2000 , NULL FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', NULL , 5000 FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 3500 , NULL FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 10000 , NULL FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 4500 , NULL FROM dual
    )
  );
```